# Fill outside RTH vs Allow pre-open

Tags: interactive-brokers

In the following drop-down, I only can select one checkbox. How to choose pre-open and after-hours both? Are not these options correspond to pre hours and after markets?

[image: Interactive Brokers TWS screenshot]

Image source: [Times in Force for Orders](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/tws/usersguidebook/ordertypes/time_in_force_for_orders.htm)

Comment: Have you asked Interactive Brokers?

Comment: What did you use to create the screenshot with jagged edges?

Comment: @Flux I thought this is a general concept. The image is from their site

Comment: @Flux SnagIt is one program (not free) that will let you crop with jagged edges.

Comment: https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/tws/usersguidebook/specializedorderentry/basic.htm . Look at "trading hour attributes".

Comment: @Lou thank you. It was handy

Answer (score 1):

I feel the labels and the doc is not very clear. [This page](https://www.brokerage-review.com/investing-firm/extended-hours/interactive-brokers-after-hours.aspx) has a clearer explanation:

> Traders who want orders to fill in the pre-market session can select “Allow pre-open” on the order ticket. This option is in the drop-down menu for duration. Another choice is “Fill outside RTH,” which will allow an order to be filled outside of regular trading hours. This second option permits orders to be filled in either the morning or evening session.